# How to get lat/lng from Facebook's location IDS

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-checkins

I have an Android/Web app where users login through FBConnect, now I have location IDs how do I convert those location IDs to lat/lng ?

e.g: these are sample location IDs with country and/or city name:

```
{"id":"110647272290207", "name":"Mohammedia,  Morocco"}

{"id":"111612325521963", "name":"Doha, Qatar"}

{"id":"116190411724975", "name":"Melbourne,  Victoria,  Australia"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution: 
here it is, it doesn't even require Access Token:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/[location_id]
```

e.g:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/116190411724975
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work anymore: 

{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104,
      "fbtrace_id": "FFKxUmtb52O"
   }
}